# Matplotlib: how to draw x axis with data

Tags: python, matplotlib

If i have data

```py
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
x = [0,1,2,3,0]
```

How can i make my x axis have the numbers 0,2,3,0 instead of it going 3 to the beginning of the plot?

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i switched the x and y in my question haha, do you know the answer?

Comment: It's the same, ``` plt.plot(x,y)```